# Possible to Create 64-bit Add-in for VBA IDE using IDTExtensibility2?

Tags: vba, com, add-in, vbe

Is it possible to create a COM add-in that will load into the Visual Basic Editor of Office 2010 64-bit? I can get my add-in to load into Office 2010 32-bit, but it just gets ignored by the 64 bit version.

EDIT:
In my research, I am finding that a lot of the popular VBE add-ins don't work for 64 bit Office (e.g. Code Cleaner, MZ Tools, VBE tools, etc). A number of these will be because they're built in 32bit VB6, but does anyone know of *any* VBA IDE add-in that works in 64 bit Office?

Comment: Perhaps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/04/09/deploying-com-add-ins-for-64-bit-office-using-visual-studio-saaid-khan-for-nathan-halstead.aspx

Comment: Hi Remou, I've looked at that page and I think it deals with add-ins within Office itself, e.g. Excel, Word, etc, rather than in the VBA IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to load an add-in into the VBA IDE. The trick is to put the registry entries under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VBA\VBE\6.0\Addins64\MyVBAAddIn.Connect, not HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VBA\VBE\6.0\Addins\MyVBAAddIn.Connect

Carlos J. Quintero has a thorough set of instructions at http://www.mztools.com/articles/2012/MZ2012013.aspx