# Is Implementing IDTExtensibility2 And Registering An Add-In Not Enough For It To Be Visible To Office?

Tags: com, office-interop, office-addins, dllregistration

So, I am trying to create a COM Add-In for 64-bit MS Office (no application in particular, just trying to get something working). I am not trying to make an add-in for the VBE, just something for the Office application itself. I have implemented IDTExtensibility2 like this (top of the file):

```
<Guid("94164866-CD9D-497A-9A8B-B476BE39749F"), 
ProgId("COM_Add-In_Test.Connection"), 
ComDefaultInterface(GetType(IDTExtensibility2)), 
ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), ComVisible(True)>
Public Class Connection
    Implements IDTExtensibility2
```

I have added registry entries under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\COM_Add-In_Test.Connection (FriendlyName, Description, and LoadBehavior).

The add-in is automatically registered for COM-Interop by Visual Studio (the box is checked).
I have also tried adding registry entries manually under HKCU\Classes\CLSID{94164866-CD9D-497A-9A8B-B476BE39749F}, but to no avail.

When I load up Excel, the add-in is not in the COM Add-Ins dialog box and nothing happens (My OnConnection method is MsgBox("Hello World!")).

I am not using any add-in framework of any kind (VSTO, ExcelDNA, etc). I have used these before, but would very much like to understand how to do this process manually.

What am I missing here?

Comment: 64-bit version of Office?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495192/possible-to-create-64-bit-add-in-for-vba-ide-using-idtextensibility2

Comment: Edited the question to address this comment.

Comment: In a question linked to the question you posted a link to, there was another link to the source code of AddInSpy. I cloned the repo and ran it, and it is saying that my CLSID registration is either incomplete or invalid. I'll focus my efforts there. Have you come across any resources detailing what exactly these registry entries need to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after doing some research, this is what I found:

1. Don't have Visual Studio register COM interop classes for you.
2. Use the RegAsm tool with the /reg argument to have it generate a .reg file for you.
3. Edit the .reg file and replace references to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT with references to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes, if you don't want to require admin rights to install. Example:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{YOUR_GUID}]
@="YOUR_PROG_ID"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{YOUR_GUID}\Implemented Categories]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{YOUR_GUID}\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45e7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{YOUR_GUID}\InprocServer32]
@="mscoree.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
"Class"="YOUR_PROG_ID"
"Assembly"="YOUR_ASSEMBLY_FULL_NAME"
"RuntimeVersion"="v4.0.30319"
"CodeBase"="file:///PATH_TO_YOUR_DLL"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{YOUR_GUID}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0]
"Class"="YOUR_PROG_ID"
"Assembly"="YOUR_ASSEMBLY_FULL_NAME"
"RuntimeVersion"="v4.0.30319"
"CodeBase"="file:///PATH_TO_YOUR_DLL"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{YOUR_GUID}\ProgId]
@="YOUR_PROG_ID"
```

4. Use add-in spy (available here: https://github.com/NetOfficeFw/AddInSpy) to help diagnose problems and monitor your progress along the way.